# Error getting default calendar for new events: Error Domain=EKCADErrorDomain Code=1013 "The operation couldn’t be completed

Tags: ios, objective-c, calendar

i am using a simple code to store calendar events programmatically i had search for many solutions on stack but all are mentioned in **SWIFT** [stack-1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25346215/error-getting-default-calendar-for-new-events-swift) [stack -2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25974555/ekcaderrordomain-using-calendarwithidentifier) and i am using **Object-C** here is the code that i use:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy"];

EKEventStore *store = [EKEventStore new];

[store requestAccessToEntityType:EKEntityMaskEvent completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"%@",error);

    if (!granted) { return; }
    EKEvent *event = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore:store];
    event.title = @"Restaurant Table";
    event.startDate = [NSDate date];

    // event.endDate = [event.startDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:60*60];  //set 1 hour meeting
    event.calendar = [store defaultCalendarForNewEvents];
    NSError *err = nil;
    [store saveEvent:event span:EKSpanThisEvent commit:YES error:&err];
    // self.savedEventId = event.eventIdentifier;  //save the event id if you want to access this later
}];
```

Thanks in advance 
and for source code here its [Programmatically add custom event in the iPhone Calendar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246249/programmatically-add-custom-event-in-the-iphone-calendar)

Comment: Sorry i was to submit the answer for other Question and replied to your Question By mistake. Really Sorry.

Comment: don`t worry can you help me with my question ?